# How to enforce PEP8 Standards in Azure DevOps Repositories?

Tags: pep8, azure-repos

I want to make sure that pushes to a ADO repository meet python PEP8 standards, and if they do not, reject them automatically. How can I enforce this?

Comment: Are you using a Git or TFVC repository?